# In-App Purchase get product programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, nsset, skproduct

I've create a `UITableView` to get my product on the store by array with id:

**Get Product ID**

```
+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{

        NSMutableArray *music = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/music/myProduct.plist"]];

        NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithArray:music];

        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

**this is the structure inside a remote plist file:**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
  <string>com.mydomain.MyApp.Prod01</string>
    <string>com.mydomain.MyApp.Prod02</string>
    <string>com.mydomain.MyApp.Prod03</string>
    <string>com.mydomain.MyApp.Prod04</string>
    <string>com.mydomain.MyApp.Prod05</string>
    <string>com.mydomain.MyApp.Prod06</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

in the TableView i can get Title, Price and Description, but i know how to get the Artwork, in iTunesConnet you have to put the cover of the product, but how can get this?

[image]

**Here is how get Price, description and name**

```
SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocal];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

So Any know how to get the Artwork from iTuneConnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot that you add in `iTunes Connect` is for review purposes by Apple only. You can not retrieve that as artwork for your app.

Quote from iTunes Connect:

> Screenshot for Review: Before you submit your `In-App Purchase` for review, you must upload a screenshot. This screenshot will be for review purposes only. It will not be displayed on the App Store.

Comment: Thats right, its just for the review guys, so they will find the In-App-Purchase Buttons

Comment: Doh! have a idea to implement a NSMutableArray with Dictionary and sub array inside the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Like @PeterFennema wrote, the screenshot is just for the guys who will review your app. So they can check the `In-App-Purchase`. Just in case they won't find it immediately.

> FYI : add a comment and tell them also as text where and how they can access the `In-App-Purchase`

For implementing the pictures you want, you have to call each single `SKProdukt` and check the `identifier`. Save the `identifier` inside a `NSDictionary` with the related `UIImage`.

The problem is just, every time you want to add some new `In-App-Purchases` you will need to upload your app again, as well as review your new `In-App-Purchases`.

Comment: and if I procede inverse? if i create a remote plist or json with > Array > dictionary >  array (prodId), array (img) in my remote server? how can divide inside the app that? maybe is better in this case you can upload product in remote mode never have to re submit for review any time